# How to pull the nested value while scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the name of the player (inside the SPAN tag) from the source code in the image.  I am able to get it based on the location:

```py
player = soup.find('td', width='50.0%')[9].get_text().strip()
```

but the location changes for different pages and returns incorrect or missing values.  Not sure how to find the "Player:" value and then have it return the name value consistently.

### HTML markup

[image: HTML markup]

Comment: Mind sharing the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find `<td>` tag with text `"Player:"` and then next `<td>` is your name:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
<tr>
    <td class="attrLabels">Grade:</td>
    <td width="50.0%">...</td>
    <td class="attrLabels">
        Player:
    </td>
    <td width="50.0%">
        <span>
            Fernando Tatis Jr.
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

name = soup.find(
    lambda tag: tag.name == "td" and tag.text.strip() == "Player:"
).find_next("td")

if name:
    print(name.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
Fernando Tatis Jr.
```

---

Or: Use CSS selector:

```
name = soup.select_one('td:contains("Player:") + td').get_text(strip=True)
print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a slight modification to Andrej Kesely's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66975535/1762224). I also passed in the `.attrLabels` class name as an option when querying.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="attrLabels">Grade: </td>
    <td width="50%">...</td>
    <td class="attrLabels">Player: </td>
    <td width="50%">
      <span>Fernando Tatis Jr.</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
'''

def extract_player_name(soup):
    label = soup.find(lambda el: el.name == 'td' and el.text.strip() == 'Player:',
        attrs = { 'class': 'attrLabels' })
    if label is None: return None
    name = label.find_next('td')
    return name.get_text(strip=True) if name is not None else None
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
    player_name = extract_player_name(soup)
    print(player_name)
```

Compiled and tested with [OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler)

---

### JavaScript version

Here is an equivalent JavaScript implementation of the code above.

```js
const extractPlayerName = () =>
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.attrLabels')]
    .find(({ textContent }) => textContent.trim() === 'Player:')
    .nextElementSibling.textContent.trim();

console.log(extractPlayerName());
```

```css
.attrLabels {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="attrLabels">Grade: </td>
    <td width="50%">...</td>
    <td class="attrLabels">Player: </td>
    <td width="50%">
      <span>Fernando Tatis Jr.</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```